# SQL Performance: Using Union and Subqueries

Tags: sql, select, join, subquery, union

Hi stackoverflow(My first question!),

We're doing something like an SNS, and got a question about optimizing queries.

Using mysql 5.1, the current table was created with:

```
CREATE TABLE friends(
 user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
 friend_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id, friend_id)
) ENGINE INNODB;
```

Sample data is populated like:

```
INSERT INTO friends VALUES
(1,2),
(1,3),
(1,4),
(1,5),
(2,1),
(2,3),
(2,4),
(3,1),
(3,2),
(4,1),
(4,2),
(5,1),
(5,6),
(6,5),
(7,8),
(8,7);
```

The business logic: we need to figure out which users are friends or friends of friends for a given user.
The current query for this for a user with user_id=1 is:

```
SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1
 UNION
 SELECT DISTINCT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id IN (
 SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1
);
```

The expected result is(order doesn't matter):

```
2
3
4
5
1
6
```

As you can see, the above query performs the subquery "SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1" twice.

So, here is the question. If performance is your primary concern, how would you change the above query or schema?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kaiTaku, I edited the question to bring out your code samples. To be honest, this probably won't be an issue unless you have a _huge_ number of records since the indexes should make it pretty fast. You may want to consider another indexes, one on user_id alone. As with _all_ optimisations, test with representative data.

Comment: @paxdiablo, Wow! Such a quick response! Sorry, I may have overwritten your edit, but thanks anyways. And you maybe right about having to do tests in order to find the best optimization.

Comment: One question, if 1 is friend with 2 then you have a row `(1, 2)`. Does your table also need a corresponding `(2, 1)` row? And is it possible to have a scenario where 1 is friend with 2 but 2 is not friends with 1. Like your MSN contact list where you can have `a@domain.com` in your list but he does not necessarily have you on his list.

Comment: Just a side note: there is no need for the DISTINCT in your example query as the UNION will remove duplicates anyway.

Comment: @Salman A, to answer your question, not necessarily. If you can do the job faster with a different style, please let me know!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I wanted to remove any duplicates in the subquery in order to increase the performance.

Comment: @kaiTaku: UNION will do that anyway, so the database will try to remove duplicates twice. So either use `UNION ALL` or leave out the DISTINCT. Having two steps to remove duplicates will not speed things up.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you're right. I've ran tests with 4.5million records with distinct and without distinct and the performance was even. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hmmm, currently outis' suggested query is the fastest, but with about 4.5 million records, the query takes 2.87 seconds to return. The slow query log states Rows_examined is 10, so the index must be working, but I can't figure out why the latency. Hardware specs ain't so bad: 2.27Ghz Xeon, 4GB mem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can use a JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f2.friend_id 
  FROM friends AS f1
    JOIN friends AS f2 ON f1.friend_id=f2.user_id OR f2.user_id=1
  WHERE f1.user_id=1;
```

Examining each query suggests the `JOIN` will about as performant as the `UNION` in a big-O sense, though perhaps faster by a constant factor. Jasie's query looks like it might be big-O faster.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1
  UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id IN (
      SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1
    );
+----+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref        | rows | Extra                                     |
+----+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | friends    | ref    | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const      |    4 | Using index                               |
|  2 | UNION              | friends    | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 16      | NULL       |   16 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | friends    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 16      | const,func |    1 | Using index                               |
| NULL | UNION RESULT       | <union1,2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL       | NULL |                                           |
+----+--------------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+


EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT f2.friend_id 
  FROM friends AS f1
    JOIN friends AS f2 
      ON f1.friend_id=f2.user_id OR f2.user_id=1
  WHERE f1.user_id=1;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f1    | ref   | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const |    4 | Using index; Using temporary                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f2    | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 16      | NULL  |   16 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------+


EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1
) OR user_id = 1;
+----+--------------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table   | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref        | rows | Extra                                     |
+----+--------------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | friends | index  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 16      | NULL       |   16 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | friends | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 16      | const,func |    1 | Using index                               |
+----+--------------------+---------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This was indeed faster! I was testing with about a million records and your query's performance was about 8x faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No need for the `UNION`. Just include an `OR` with the `user_id` of the beginning user:

```
SELECT DISTINCT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1
) OR user_id = 1;

+-----------+
| friend_id |
+-----------+
|         2 |
|         3 |
|         4 |
|         5 |
|         1 |
|         6 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Must've been too easy for you